# filter then count for many different threshold

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate the number of lines that satisfy a condition on a very large dataframe which can be achieved by

```
df.filter(col("value") >= thresh).count()
```

I want to know the result for each threshold in range `[1, 10]`. Enumerate each threshold then do this action will scan the dataframe for 10 times. It's slow.

If I can achieve it by scanning the df only once?

Comment: just filter by the threshold and group by it, then use window function row_number and take the last row.

Comment: I don't know if such a function exists. A solution could be to create a list with 10 elements (one by threshold), then scan the dataframe "by hand" and increment the right values in the list according to the currently read value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an indicator column for each threshold, then sum:

```py
import random
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(value=random.randint(0,10)) for _ in range(1_000_000)])

df.select([
    (F.col("value") >= thresh)
    .cast("int")
    .alias(f"ind_{thresh}") 
    for thresh in range(1,11)
]).groupBy().sum().show()

# +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
# |sum(ind_1)|sum(ind_2)|sum(ind_3)|sum(ind_4)|sum(ind_5)|sum(ind_6)|sum(ind_7)|sum(ind_8)|sum(ind_9)|sum(ind_10)|
# +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
# |    908971|    818171|    727240|    636334|    545463|    454279|    363143|    272460|    181729|      90965|
# +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation with `when` expressions should do the job.

Here's an example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (4,), (6,), (7,)], ["value"])

count_expr = [
    F.count(F.when(F.col("value") >= th, 1)).alias(f"gte_{th}")
    for th in range(1, 11)
]

df.select(*count_expr).show()
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
#|gte_1|gte_2|gte_3|gte_4|gte_5|gte_6|gte_7|gte_8|gte_9|gte_10|
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
#|    7|    6|    5|    4|    2|    2|    1|    0|    0|     0|
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a user-defined function `udf` from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(20)), columns=['val'])
thres =  [90, 80, 30]     # these are the thresholds
thres.sort(reverse=True)  # list needs to be sorted

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[2]") \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .getOrCreate()
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(df)

myUdf = udf(lambda x: 0 if x>thres[0] else 1 if x>thres[1] else 2 if  x>thres[2] else 3)
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("rank", myUdf(sparkDF.val))
sparkDF.show()
# +---+----+                                                                      
# |val|rank|
# +---+----+
# | 28|   3|
# | 54|   2|
# | 19|   3|
# |  4|   3|
# | 74|   2|
# | 62|   2|
# | 95|   0|
# | 19|   3|
# | 55|   2|
# | 62|   2|
# | 33|   2|
# | 93|   0|
# | 81|   1|
# | 41|   2|
# | 80|   2|
# | 53|   2|
# | 14|   3|
# | 16|   3|
# | 30|   3|
# | 77|   2|
# +---+----+
sparkDF.groupby(['rank']).count().show()
# Out: 
# +----+-----+
# |rank|count|
# +----+-----+
# |   3|    7|
# |   0|    2|
# |   1|    1|
# |   2|   10|
# +----+-----+
```

A value gets rank `i` if it's strictly greater than `thres[i]` but smaller or equal `thres[i-1]`. This should minimize the number of comparisons.

For `thres = [90, 80, 30]` we have the ranks 0-> `[max, 90[`, 1-> `[90, 80[`, 2->`[80, 30[`, 3->`[30, min]`